# How many athletes from Korea participated in summer Olympics of 2000? i have to sove this "SQL query" in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES(
  ID numeric(22) NOT NULL,
  NATION_ID numeric(22),
  GAME_ID numeric(22),
  ATHLETE_ID numeric(22)
);
ALTER TABLE OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES
ADD FOREIGN KEY (NATION_ID) REFERENCES  OLYM_NATIONS(ID);

ALTER TABLE OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES
ADD FOREIGN KEY (GAME_ID) REFERENCES  OLYM_GAMES(ID);

ALTER TABLE OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ATHLETE_ID) REFERENCES  OLYM_ATHLETES(ID);
```

[image]

the Query I tried was this:

```
SELECT count(ATH.ATHLETE_ID) AS ATHLETE_ID_CNT,ATH.GAME_ID AS GAME_ID,ATH.NATION_ID AS NATION_ID
 FROM  OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES ATH
 INNER JOIN OLYM_ATHLETE_GAMES ATHS
ON ATH.ID = ATHS.ATHLETE_ID
WHERE  ATH.NATION_ID = 4
AND
ATH.GAME_ID = 1
```

; 
but no correct answers!

Comment: could you please post your data as text and also show which result you expect

Comment: ATH.NATION_ID = 4 - isn't that denmark , and do you need a join at all?

Comment: I have solved it...thanks for the responses ....appreciate it